# Finding a specific value out of an Array (RoR / MySQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find a specific value inside an `array`. The `array` is composed from data in `MySQL` database and looks like:

```
info = [#<Info1: bla, Info2: blo>,#<Info1: bli, Info2, Ble>]
```

Now I want to get every `Info1`'s value from it, but I do not know how.

The `array` was formed by calling

```
info = Info.find(:all)
```

Can anyone help me?

I am using `Rails 2.2.2` (don't ask, can't do anything about it) and `Ruby 1.8`.

Edit: More details

Info is a database, where Info1 and info 2 are the columns. Calling it with info = Info.find(:all) returns the array above.

What I have tried so far involves trying to go through the array with each, but so far no luck.

Most of what I have tried like

```
a.grep(/^info1/)
```

and

```
info.select(|i| i.name == "info1")
```

all return empty arrays

**Edit**

Nevermind, I found the answer. I was thinking too weird. The answer is

```
info.each do |object|
puts object.info2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your selection criteria? You can do something like

```
info.select{|i| i.name == 'hello' }
```

and you will get all the Info objects with name = 'hello'.

But I would prefer to change the query, if you can, to filter them in the database query directly.

Comment: I tried it and returns me an empty hash. Changing it in the database query isn't really an option here, it's an assignment and I am actually right where I need to be, I just can't go on.

Comment: if info is an array, you can't have an hash back since `select` returns an array. So maybe you have an empty array. Can you add some more info in the question about the `Info` attributes and your filter? Also writing down what you tried would help